# Laravel Repositories whereHas -- multiple

Tags: laravel, eloquent, repository-pattern

I have the following repository `Products` and each product can have many `Categories` and many `Bidders`

What I am trying to achieve is the following (Without Repository)

```
$products = Products::whereHas('categories', function ($category) {


})->whereHas('bidders', function ($bidder) {

})->get();
```

This works fine, however, I am trying to make it so that repositories are in place and you can still do the `whereHas` query, so in my repository I created a method:

```
public function whereHas($attribute, \Closure $closure = null)
{
    return $this->model->whereHas($attribute, $closure);
}
```

This works well, but only if I am using one of them in my main query, whereas if I use multiple:

```
$products = $this->products->whereHas('categories', function ($category) {
   $category->where('id', '=', 1);
})->whereHas('bidders', function($bidders) {

})->get();
```

I am getting the following error:

`Unknown column 'has_relation'`

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'has_relation' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where exists (select * from
>   `categories` inner join `products_categories` on `categories`.`id` =
>   `products_categories`.`categories_id` where `products`.`id` =
>   `products_categories`.`products_id` and `id` = 1) and (`has_relation`
>   = sections))

The issue I'm seeing is that its returning a collection of items on the first `whereHas` which means it cannot compute the second one. Any ideas to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a closure with multiple relations to `whereHas`

```
$products = $this->products->whereHas(['categories', function 
        ($category) {
  $category->where('id', '=', 1);
},'bidders' => function($bidders) {

}])->get();
```

It will work as expected.